# Accessing collection index in Handlebars/Blaze #each loop

Tags: html, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm messing around with a Meteor Leaderboard example.  Let's say I wanted to display the index of an item inside a handlebars #each loop:

```
{{#each players}}
  {{> player}}
{{/each}}

<template name="player">
  <div class="player {{selected}}">
    <span class="index">{{index}}</span>
    <span class="name">{{name}}</span>
    <span class="score">{{score}}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

Normally one would write a handlebars helper for this, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get it working with a Meteor collection.

How would one do this?  Thank you.

Comment: Did you actually try the handlebars helper approach? [This snippet](https://gist.github.com/1371586) worked for me.

Comment: @zwip Thanks a bunch.  I had tried, but using a different helper.

Answer (score 4):

There is now an @index feature in Blaze:

```
{{#each players}}
  {{> player index=@index}}
{{/each}}

<template name="player">
  <div class="player {{selected}}">
    <span class="index">{{index}}</span>
    <span class="name">{{name}}</span>
    <span class="score">{{score}}</span>
  </div>
</template>

Template.player.helpers({
  index() {
    var data = Template.currentData();
    if( data ) {
      return data.index;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to show the mongo generated id just use _id

```
 <span class="id">{{_id}}</span>
```

It will show the unique index id in the collection.  It won't be pretty.

I may have misunderstood your question. Sorry if I did.

Comment: Just found this!  I wanted the index, so it would show 0,1,2 etc next to the player.  Basically the position of the player in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer for this question. I had to put some hours figuring it out

In your client

`Template.player.data = function(data){`

`if(type){`

`return Template[ 'player' ](data);`

`}`

`}`

In your template

`{{#each players}}`

`{{data this}}`

`{{/each}}`

This will work seamlessly.

Comment: I get an error that type is undefined, what does it represent here in your example?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved this - not a perfect solution - by using the fact that Mongo typically creates indexes that increase in value.

```
Template.item.index = function() {
    return Items.find().count() - Items.find({_id: {$lte: this._id}}).count() + 1
}
```

I then use this in the template like so:
    {{index}}

Hope this helps!